# how to Exclude the list of selected files in powershell

Tags: powershell

In $FilesInContainer2 the exclude function is not working as expected.

**I need the list of files from $files which is not in $FilesInContainer1**

```
$srcdir = "W:\XXX\"
$zipFilepath = "W:\YYY"
$currentFileExtension = ".txt"
$logFileName = "W:\Log.txt"

$files = Get-ChildItem $srcdir -Filter *.txt | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get- 
Date).Date} | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending
$Container1FileCount = [math]::Ceiling(($files).count/2)
$FilesInContainer1 = $files | Select-Object -First $Container1FileCount
$FilesInContainer2 = Get-ChildItem $files -Exclude $FilesInContainer1
```

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and explain what kind of behavior you are expecting. Also explain what you are trying to achieve, maybe there's better a way. *Do not add a comment*; the question should be understandable without reading the comment thread.

Comment: on win7ps5.1 the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters REQUIRE using the `-Recurse` parameter. you don't seem to have done that. ///// also, as `vonPryz` pointed out ... you have not mentioned what "not working as expected" means ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Below code will write the list of files from $files which is not in $FilesInContainer1**

$FilesInContainer2 = $files | ?{$FilesInContainer1 -notcontains $_}

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do a `Get-ChildItem` twice at all?

To split the collection of files obtained with the first `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, you can simply split that in two by doing something like this:

```
$srcdir = 'W:\XXX'

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcdir -Filter '*.txt' -File | 
            Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).Date} | 
            Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending
$half  = [math]::Ceiling(($files.Count / 2))

# get the first half of the files colection
$FilesInContainer1 = $files | Select-Object -First $half 
# or use $FilesInContainer1 = $files[(0..($half - 1))]

# get the rest (second half) of the files collection
$FilesInContainer2 = $files | Select-Object -Last ($files.Count - $half)
# or use $FilesInContainer2 = $files[($half..($files.Count - 1))]
```